# Tube Size Available in US?

Tags: innertube

Is it possible to still purchase tubes for Continental 47-622 TravelMaster tires with 28x1.75 written on the side?
I had an old Rabeneick commuter bike (have no idea of the bike's age)  shipped back from Germany that I'm trying to put back together. I've never seen valves like these....they're not Schraeder or Presta.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If it actually measures 47mm wide inflated then it's a little caught between 2 sizes, but 700x45 tubes will work fine in it. 29x1.95-2.135ish tubes would also work, but be big. If it's Dunlop/Woods valve now then get Schrader. If it's Regina get Presta.

Comment: 700x38-48 or 40-50 are quite common ranges. I don't buy expensive tubes and have only ever seen ranges of around 10mm on the width (or a bit more)

Comment: Great... Gives me a direction to head, as well as ideas to identify the valve types....have only been around road bikes so this will be interesting! Now to address the stem bolt and wedge fiasco! Appreciate the help!

Comment: 700x38-48 and 700x40-50 may exist but they are in no way common, at all. The common labeled sizes in that area are 38-45 and 40-45. And from there it goes to the 29er sizes.